# Why does AutoPy fail to merge multiple Python files when they are in different directories?

Tags: python, executable, auto-py-to-exe

I have 6 different python files lets say numbered 1 to 6. 1 is the main GUI and based on buttons pressed on main gui, 2 to 6 are executed to perform their respective work. AutoPy merges them into a single window based executable file, but when I run the executable file it cannot run scripts 2 to 6 and says no such file or directory.

If I place the python files in the same directory, though, it works. How do I get over this?

Comment: Apparently you get over this by placing the files in the same directory. Why don't you do it like that?

Comment: I dont want it because i want one single executable to run. The 1st file tries for google sign in. If sign in is successful, it matches record with a spreadsheet if user is paid. if thats ok, it runs other scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try to import all your scripts in main file as **classes**.

Do this for scripts 2 to 6 :

```
 class Script2:
    def workScript2(self, argument1, ...) :
```

In your main.py file which lanches the GUI :

```
from script2 import Script2
.
.
```

Then you'll use auto-py to generate one executable file base on the main.py